# C#: How to set member arrays of an unsafe struct

Tags: c#, c++

I am working on a VS 2015 MVC C# web application that loads a 3rd party C++ DLL I do not have source code for. The DLL requires an input param. The new spec requires a couple of array members. One is an `int` array and the other is a `char` array.

My C# struct defines the intended `char` array as `byte` to match the 8-bit C++ char:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct MyDLLInput
{
    public fixed int SomeList[288];
    public fixed byte PathToData[256];
};
```

The struct seems correct to me, but now I need to set values and I'm not having any success.

```
MyDLLInput dllInput = new MyDLLInput()
{
    SomeList = new int[] {0,12,33,67,93},
    PathToData = "C:\\some\\path\\to\\data"
}

// Call 3rd Party DLL
MyDLLOutput = MyDLL.EntryPoint(MyDLLInput);
```

For both member arrays I am getting the following error:

> Fixed size buffers can only be accessed through locals or fields.

There are at least a couple of things going on here - aside from the proper way of setting the values using a local I also have to make an encoding conversion from `string` to `byte[]`.

Can someone provide me with a code example of a clean way to set these values?

Comment: You need to instantiate fixed fields in unsafe block.

Comment: Encoding.GetBytes will solve your second problem https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there some reason you're using an unsafe struct?  Can you not use marshalling attributes?  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eshywdt7(v=vs.110).aspx

Regardless, you need to know how you're converting from a C# string to a byte array, and that depends on what encoding your C++ DLL expects that string to be in.  For example, on Windows, it is often the "ANSI code page", but on Linux/Unix it might be either "current locale" or explicitly "UTF-8".

So, one option that gives you the most control over the encoding would be to do somethiing like:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MyDllInput
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 288)]
        public int[] SomeList;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
        public byte[] PathToData;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyDllInput dllInput = new MyDllInput()
        {
            SomeList = new int[288],
            PathToData = new byte[256]
        };

        var listData = new int[] { 0, 12, 33, 67, 93 };
        Array.Copy(listData, dllInput.SomeList, listData.Length);

        var pathToDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("C:\\some\\path\\to\\data");
        Array.Copy(pathToDataBytes, dllInput.PathToData, pathToDataBytes.Length);
    }
```

Alternatively, instead of doing the encoding conversion directly, you can try declaring the PathToData as a string and then using a marshalling attribute to have C# convert it for you; see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MyDllInput
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 288)]
        public int[] SomeList;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst =256)]
        public String PathToData;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyDllInput dllInput = new MyDllInput()
        {
            SomeList = new int[288],
            PathToData = "C:\\some\\path\\to\\data"
        };            

        var listData = new int[] { 0, 12, 33, 67, 93 };
        Array.Copy(listData, dllInput.SomeList, listData.Length);
    }
```

In the second case, it's important that when you declare EntryPoint you set the CharSet property on the DllImportAttribute to get the string conversion to happen the way you want.  In your case, you *probably* want CharSet.Ansi since your DLL takes a char* and not a wchar_t*.  For example,

```
    [DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern void EntryPoint(ref MyDllInput input);
```

Comment: Your example is excellent and I hope it works for me. I can't try it right at this moment but I will a little later when I get to my desk. As for using a marshalling attribute, it's another option I wasn't sure how to setup and the project was nearing it's scheduled deadline. Once I had it all working I left it alone to meet the deadline. I'm going to try your suggestions and will provide an update later this evening. Thank you for taking the time. I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: I am trying your first example, but I receive `Type could not be marshaled because the length of an embedded array instance does not match the declared length in the layout.` Is this caused because my `int[] SomeList` does not contain 288 elements in the array and/or `byte[] PathToData` is not exactly 256 bytes? SomeList will not always be initialized with 288 elements - sometimes only 1 element and of course, PathToData is not exactly 256 bytes length. Just wondering if this is why I'm getting the error and if so, how might this be overcome?

Comment: I think you're right -- I was assuming that C# would zero-extend the arrays, but I guess it won't do that automatically.  You can try manually extend your arrays to the right size.  For example, you could allocate an array of the correct size and then copy from your smaller array to the correctly-sized array using Array.Copy().

Comment: I know this question has been marked as answered. Maybe I should ask a new one, but I think this is considered related. When I call the DLL's entry point I get an exception - `Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.` I've read other SO questions/answers, but not able to see how they help. Does it stand out to you why I would be receiving this error? Remember, I do not have access to the C++ source code for the 3rd party DLL. I'll ask a new question if you think I should.

Comment: I have asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902919/c-sharp-calling-c-3rd-party-dll-no-source-raises-exception-not-pinvoke-com