# C# calling C++ 3rd party DLL (no source) raises exception - not PInvoke Compatible

Tags: c#, c++, dll, struct, marshalling

I am using VS 2015 Community with an ASP.NET MVC Web Application that uses a 3rd party C++ DLL I do not have source code for. Documentation is very scarce as is any helpful communication with the authors of the 3rd party DLL.

I've asked a related [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843050/c-how-to-set-member-arrays-of-an-unsafe-struct/37843378) and received a good answer from @Steven. I've modified my code according to his answer and am trying to make a successful call to the 3rd party C++ DLL. The code:

## // Call DLL

```
MyDLLInput _DLLInput = new MyDLLInput();
{
    SomeList = new int[288],
    ...
    SomeInt = 22,
    SomeDbl = 1.45,
    ...
    PathtoData = "C:\\Some\\Path\\To\\Data"
};    

var ids = new int[] { 0, 12, 33, 67, 93 };
Array.Copy(ids, _DLLInput.SomeList, ids.Length);

// Call DLL Entry Point
MyDLLOutput _DLLOutput = MyDLL.Unit(_DLLInput);
```

Raises exception:

> **Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.**

**// C# Input STRUCT**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MyDLLInput
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 288)]
    public int[] SomeList;
    ...
    public int SomeInt;
    public double SomeDbl;
    
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string PathtoData;
};
```

**// C# Output STRUCT**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MyDLLOutput
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 288)]
    public int[] SomeList;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 288)]
    public double[] SomeDblArray;
    ...
    public int SomeInt;        // Same as input
    public double SomeDbl;     // Same as input
}
```

**// C# DLLImport**

```
public class MyDLL
{
    [DllImport("My_DLL.dll",
        EntryPoint = "?Unit@@YA?AUDLLOutput@@UDLLInput@@@Z",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern MyDLLOutput Unit(MyDLLInput UnitInput);
}
```

**// C++ My_DLL.h**

```
#define  EPS_API __declspec(dllexport) 

struct DLLInput
{
    int SomeList[288];

    int SomeInt;
    double SomeDbl;

    char PathtoData[256];
};

struct DLLOutput
{
    int SomeList[288];
    double SomeDblArray[288];
    ...
    int SomeInt;
    double SomeDbl;
};

EPS_API DLLOutput Unit(DLLInput UnitInput);
```

I think I must be close, but haven't been able to find any SO or Google results that help. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the EntryPoint right?  It unmangles to `LOutput const volatile __cdecl Unit(struct DLLInput)`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I see what you are referring to and have fixed it in my example. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any other types in your output struct, like `char[]`?  From [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201996/c-sharp-methods-type-signature-is-not-pinvoke-compatible) your output type needs to be blittable, and char arrays are not (they need to be strings).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The op in the SO question you refer to seems to have fixed his problem with char[] by using a string, but my output struct contains only `int`, `double`, `int[]` and `double[]` which all seem to be blittable types according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx - still stumped. Anyone else see why I am getting this exception?

Comment: Your C# DLLOutput is wrong. It should have 3 members SomeList, SomeInt, SomeDbl, it has four. Is this the actual code you are using?

Comment: @Ben No, it's not complete code. There are actually about 3 dozen members. All of which are `int`, `double`, `int[]`, `double[]` members. I've checked and rechecked - my output struct appears to be accurate according to the .h - I'll edit the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Everything must be exactly correct on return - every array member must have the marshalling attributes, with the correct UnmanagedType and SizeConst etc. Unless it is, the stack will be unbalanced on return and you will get this exception.

Comment: @Ben I do have every array member marshalled in my code.

Comment: That the DLL owner is unresponsive is not a surprise, this function was not written by a professional programmer.  Pretty unlikely that he's still around.  Do everything you can to avoid using this product, the very clumsy function signature is probably not the only problem you are going to encounter.  If you must then you have do this with a C++/CLI project.

Comment: @HansPassant No disagreement here, except that the current DLL is the fourth one provided to me over a couple of years - written by the man that signs my checks... he is very much still with the multi-billion dollar/year company. This particular DLL is new and uses arrays for performance reasons (this DLL calls yet another `4th` party DLL). I know you are right, but we will work it out. I have made some suggestions to him as I realize the current structure is NOT ideal. I wish I knew C++ well enough to do it myself. In this case he may be better than me. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can pass a struct by copy with P/Invoke (although I'm not 100% sure).  That's why my answer declared the struct as "ref" in C# (in C++, that would mean a pointer-to-DllInput, not just a DllInput).  I suspect that's what is causing your error message.  At this point, you could try making a DLL of your own which acts as a stub to the other DLL, but with wrapper functions declared in a P/Invoke-compatible way.  For example, by declaring a function like void CallUnit(DllInput* input, DllOutput* output)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what Ben has said.

You need to remove the const definitions to outside the interopable struct. By declaring a layout of the struct as sequential the compiler is expecting EXACTLY the same number of members, declared in EXACTLY the same order, with each type declared, EXACTLY the same size on both sides (i.e in C++ and C#). Those `const` declarations add to the memory layout and so the signatures are not compatible.

`char` is not the same size in C# and C++, `byte` is (although they can change depending on the platform, both types are guaranteed at least 8 bits). You could marshall a `byte` array instead of a `string`, but either is fine.

To Create a `byte` array which is compatible with C++ `char` array (same size).

```
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
public byte[] PathToData = new byte[256];
PathToData = utf8.GetBytes(pathToDataString);
```

On another note though, if documentation is scarce and the authors are not helpful, personally I would think twice about using this 3rd party. Calling it is one thing, debugging it is another.

Comment: I had the PInvoke Compatibility issue prior to adding the const in each struct. I saw another MS example that defined a const for array sizes, but I didn't know it caused overhead in the signature. Although I now have it removed with arrays defined with `[288]` instead, I still have the same issue. I have also checked each and every member to be sure they are defined exactly as the 3rd party DLL's .h. I'll edit my question and remove the `const` - are you saying other than that it 'looks' like I am coded correctly?

Comment: I've triple-checked that all members are defined and in the exact order as the .h - I also have every `int[]` and `double[]` set with marshalling attributes as per my code above. The only members I do not have marshalled are `int` and `double` members. I don't see a way of marshalling those. There are no other types in the output struct.

Comment: @rwkiii You don't have to marshall a single double or int, they are POD. Array versions would have to be marshalled.

Comment: I would have thought that const delcaration would be present in the memory layout since you have defined it within the struct and declared the struct sequential. To be honest it all looks ok by eyeballing it, just trundled through some old interop code and the only differences to anything that I did (in terms of interop/marshalling) is to not explicity state the char encoding and to marshall C# strings as UnmanagedType.LPStr. Of course I had the source since I wrote the dll's so it was a bit easier for me to debug and get working.

Comment: Apologies, You can't marshall the string as UnmanagedType.LPStr as it is required in char[] form as stated in the dll interface.

Comment: I could remove the char encoding and just use `byte[]` though I had already tried that with the same result. Yes, I wish I had the source code. The C++ DLL is written by someone with the same company and is specifically for use in the web app I am responsible for so it's not so easy to not use it. ;)

Comment: Do you have a feel for whether the problem is caused by the input or output struct? I just noted an error in the VS output window: `Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' in WEBAPP.dll`. Makes me wonder if the .h is not accurate, but I'm fairly positive that it would be since the DLL was tested prior to my receiving it and the .h is up to date. Frustrating...

Comment: Personally I feel the problem is marshaling the C# 'string' on the input 'struct'. Rather than marshal as a 'string', I would convert it to a 'byte[]' array using UTF8 and marshal that.

Comment: I feel your answer is perfectly acceptable. I hesitate marking it as the answer as I don't want to mislead anyone who pulls this question up in a search. What you have told me is good info, although I must be facing a different issue since I'm still not fixed. I have requested full source code to the C++ DLL so that I can look at it myself. It might pop out at me, maybe not. I will update this question once I have had a chance to review the C++ source. Thank you very much.

Comment: One thing of interest is that I think the input struct is correct since `PathToData` is the very last member in the input struct. If it, or the struct in general, were not correct the 3rd party DLL would not be able to access the SQLite3 data. I can see via ProcMon that the data is being accessed correctly. I can see all of the dependencies being loaded by SQLite3 and the data directory/data getting accessed successfully. Though I can't see in ProcMon where there is a failure at least I can see the input is working. Still, I see nothing wrong with the output struct declaration. FYI...

Comment: @rwkiii, no worries, wait and see if anyone else has something to add. If you can, post the relevant source for the dll if you are still having problems and we can go from there.